# Sass extend doesn't extend hover anymore

Tags: sass

```
%extendor
  color: blue
  &:hover
    color: red

.something
  &, .more-specific & 
    @extend %extendor
```

Produces the following results:

*Sass < 3.2, libsass 2.0*

```
.something, .more-specific .something {
  color: blue; }
  .something:hover, .more-specific .something:hover {
    color: red; }
```

*Sass 3.2+*

```
.something, .more-specific .something {
  color: blue;
}
.something:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

How do I get the "new Sass" behave like before ?

Answer (score 0):

Sass does not have any sort of "legacy behavior" settings.  You have 3 options:

- Submit a bug report to the maintainers of Sass and wait for them to fix the problem
- Fix Sass yourself and submit a patch for it
- Continue using the version of Sass that has the behavior you're looking for

Alternately, you could stop repeating classes in your selector:

```
%extendor
  color: blue
  &:hover
    color: red

.something, .something-else 
  @extend %extendor
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/b03378b29ae1570217ca

Comment: I filed a bug report. Lets see what that does. The selector looks off, I know, but sometimes you've got to do what you've got to do...

Comment: Heya, an invitation for you http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18702325#18702325